# How do I create an opaque overlay of an area on a Pdf using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using `itextsharp`. All I want to do is create an opaque overlay of an area on a `Pdf`. The code I have so far creates a blue rectangle but I can see everything underneath. I want it to hide what is underneath. Here is the code:

```
var cb = writer.DirectContent;
cb.SetColorStroke(BaseColor.BLUE);
cb.Rectangle(10, 10, 560, 350);
cb.FillStroke();
```

Comment: Which content covers what depends on the order in which you add content. If you add content first, then add the rectangle, the rectangle will cover the content. If you add the rectangle first, then add the content, the content will cover the content.

Comment: Note that, even if you cover content, the content will always be there. People will always be able to copy/paste text underneath the rectangle. If you want to avoid that, you need to apply redaction (you might want to switch to iText 7 if you need redaction).

Comment: Oh, ok, let me try something

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Putting the fill logic last, before closing everything does exactly what I want.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for that, I've credited you in the answer.

Comment: OK, thanks! I've upvoted the answer. I think you can also accept your own answer.

Comment: Excellent, it says I can accept it in 2 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @BrunoLowagie, I've answered my own question. Simply, putting the fill logic last, after all other overlays and the like makes the area opaque:

```
cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE);
cb.Rectangle(filledOverlay.X, filledOverlay.Y, filledOverlay.Width, filledOverlay.Height);
cb.Fill();
```